# Solr DatImportHandler, multiple resuls of the same type?

Tags: lucene, solr, dataimporthandler

Hey guys, some help here would as always be greatly appreciated.

I'm indexing data from a db using Solr. Each row in the first table, event_titles, can have more than one start date associated with it, contained in the table event_dates. Data-config is as follows;

```
<entity name="events"
  query="select id,title_id,name,summary,description,type from event_titles">
  <entity name="events"
    query="select start from event_dates where title_id = '${events.title_id}'">
  </entity>
</entity>
```

Using the DIH Develpment Console, I can see that it returns each date as it should, but it only ever saves the first one, for example;

```
<lst name="entity:event_dates">
  <str name="query">
    select start from event_dates where title_id = '38947'
  </str>
  <str name="time-taken">0:0:0.10</str>
  <str>----------- row #1-------------</str>
  <date name="start">2010-04-25T23:00:00Z</date>
  <str>---------------------------------------------</str>
  <str>----------- row #2-------------</str>
  <date name="start">2010-04-26T23:00:00Z</date>
  <str>---------------------------------------------</str>
  <str>----------- row #3-------------</str>
  <date name="start">2010-04-27T23:00:00Z</date>
  <str>---------------------------------------------</str>
</lst>
```

But, the result when you run a select is as follows....

```
...
<arr name="start">
<date>2010-04-25T23:00:00Z</date>
</arr>
...
```

I would have though it would put all the returned dates into the start 'array'?

Can anyone shed any light on whether this is even possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, multiValued in schema should be set to true.